# Haskell: Using the correct instance for a type wrapped in another type

Tags: haskell, types

Say we have the following code, where a couple of types end up being place inside two other types, the outer-most of which is a GADT:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances,
             GADTSyntax,
             GADTs,
             OverlappingInstances,
             StandaloneDeriving #-}

data SomeType1 = SomeType1 deriving Show
data SomeType2 = SomeType2 deriving Show

class SomeClass d where

instance SomeClass SomeType1 where
instance SomeClass SomeType2 where

data WrapperType t where
  WrapperType :: (SomeClass t, Show t) => t -> (WrapperType t)

instance Show (WrapperType SomeType1) where
  show (WrapperType d) = "correct"

instance Show (WrapperType t) where
  show (WrapperType d) = "incorrect"

data ListWrap where
  ListWrap :: [(WrapperType d)] -> ListWrap

deriving instance Show ListWrap
```

Now, writing `[WrapperType SomeType1]` gives me what I want:

```
*MyModule> [WrapperType SomeType1]
[correct]
```

But as soon as I put it inside `ListWrap` I get the wrong `Show` instance picked to display the contents:

```
*MyModule> ListWrap [WrapperType SomeType1]
ListWrap [incorrect]
```

There must be something about type classes and/or GADTs that I'm failing to understand -- what could it be?

Comment: type class resolution is done at compile time and with that existential the type of `d` in `WrapperType d` is stored inside the `ListWrap` is a runtime thing

Comment: Can this be resolved with manual type annotations? (Also, the helpful answer below seems to have been deleted before I got a chance to read it properly, not sure why).

Comment: I deleted it because I posted a little prematurely—it still wasn't working even when you accounted for deleted type information. I just undeleted it adding that extra bit.

Comment: I'm also honestly a little uncertain what the intended behavior here is—it's using a lot of extensions which tend to put instance resolution into the haze for me. Type inference begins to need a lot of help.

Comment: @EdwardLilley Manual annotations of what? It's an existential type. Imagine if you where to return an existential which a witness selected based on some IO, then unbox it and stick it in `WrapperType` then into `ListWrap`. THis is clearly halting problem territory

Comment: I'd show an example, but I can't fit it in a comment

Comment: @jozefg Do you know why the non-existentially typed version in my answer still wasn't resolving to the right instance?

Comment: Ok, I see that I can't just lose information by going into `ListWrap` and then magically regain it again.

Comment: You kind of can using `Typeable` and `cast` https://gist.github.com/tel/6118064.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the derived code (with `-ddump-deriv`) then you can see that the derived instance for `ListWrap` is pretty normal looking

```
instance Show ListWrap where
  showsPrec a (ListWrap b) =
    showParen (a >= 11) $ showString "ListWrap " . showsPrec 11 b
```

it's just passing the inner show down to `showsPrec` again. This suggests that the problem is that GHC is erasing the type variable `d` when you wrap it with ListWrap. Indeed, you could also write `ListWrap` as

```
data ListWrap where
  ListWrap :: forall d. [(WrapperType d)] -> ListWrap
```

which emphasizes that this is existentially typed.

We can see the error more directly by deleting the `instance Show (WrapperType t)` and observing GHC's type error

```
/Users/tel/tmp/foo.hs:33:52: Warning:
    No instance for (Show (WrapperType d))
      arising from a use of `showsPrec'
    Possible fix:
      add an instance declaration for (Show (WrapperType d))
    In the second argument of `(.)', namely `showsPrec 11 b'
    In the second argument of `($)', namely
      `showString "ListWrap " . showsPrec 11 b'
    In the expression:
      showParen (a >= 11) $ showString "ListWrap " . showsPrec 11 b
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
```

In other words, it has lost the details about the `d` type and thus cannot unify the specific `instance Show (WrapperType SomeType1)`.

---

Now you would think that this would imply that keeping that type information around would make the type error go away.

```
data ListWrap d where
  ListWrap :: [(WrapperType d)] -> ListWrap d

> show $ ListWrap [WrapperType SomeType1]
"ListWrap [incorrect]"
```

But it seems like the instance search is going awry as well. The only way I could find to make it work was to turn on `UndecidableInstances` and provide a suggestion for instance derivation.

```
deriving instance Show (WrapperType d) => Show (ListWrap d)
```

after which the example works

```
> show $ ListWrap [WrapperType SomeType1]
"ListWrap [correct]"
```

Comment: It should be noted that *every* type variable in a GADT declaration is implicitly universally quantified. There's no scoping like in regular ADTs (so writing the forall doesn't emphasize much, any more than it would with a regular function declaration).

Comment: What's the core for the non-existential implementation of `deriving Show`? I wonder if the type is getting erased anyways or if it's just the type class resolution algorithm doing weird things.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for finding a way of making it work! I had no idea that you could use type variables inside other types as arguments to classes (in the deriving instance), so I don't understand exactly what's going on there.

Comment: All `Show` instances do actually have proper instances which do actual `show`-ing, in various type-dependent ways (if that's what you're asking); this was just a minimal example.

Comment: @schachaf Yeah, it doesn't change anything, just emphasizes the where the binding for `d` is coming from.

Comment: @EdwardLilley By using `d` twice I'm telling GHC that it must unify the two type variables. For some type `d` it must find both an `instance Show (WrapperType d)` in order to form an `instance Show (ListWrap d)`.

Comment: Oh right, so the sort of thing that counts as a constraint (on the right-hand-side of a `=>`) can be very liberal indeed? Or is this specifically a result of using UndecidableInstances?

Comment: Undecidable instances *is* required in this case since on the right side we have `d` wrapped in one constructor and on the left we have `d` wrapped in one constructor. Haskell can't prove that `d` is getting simpler from right to left so it's afraid of an infinite loop in typechecking.